# How to change js src by user's typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-api, google-books

I am using Google Books API PHP and would like to change search key word when user types it in order to return immediate title tips. How to implement so that `q=what user types right now`?

```
<script src="https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=harry+potter&callback=handleResponse"></script>
```

Comment: Each time a user types you will include that script?

Answer (score 1):

To do this efficiently, remove `&callback=handleResponse` so the actual response you get back is JSON.

In your javascript set a variable as so:

```
var request = 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes';
```

Have a form (containing textarea and submit) handler with something like this:

```
$('#form').onsubmit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var keywords = $('#myTextAreaInputInsideTheForm').val();
  $.getJSON(request + '?q=' + keywords, function(data){
     //do stuff with the json response
     console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Or if you require the XMLHTTPrequest to be called everytime something changes within the textarea

```
$('#myTextArea').on('keyup', function(){
      var keywords = $(this).val();
      $.getJSON(request + '?q=' + keywords, function(data){
         //do stuff with the json response
         console.log(data);
      });
});
```

**EDIT:** I'm assuming you're using textarea, but `<input type="text"/>` works as well.

**EDIT2:** [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9xk30hsp/) The demo may not work because google now returns a 403 forbidden. You must not call URL too many times or google will bloc your request. I recommend calling it every couple of letters written. Good luck.

```
var request = 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes';
$('#myTextArea').on('keyup', function(){

      var keywords = $(this).val();
    if(keywords.length > 0 && keywords.length % 5 == 0){
          $.getJSON(request + '?q=' + keywords, function(data){
             //do stuff with the json response
             console.log(data);
          });
    }
});
```

Using `keyup` is better than change.

Comment: @Vinand you're going to have to be a little more specific. Which part doesn't work?